# Core Data fetch with Predicate of transient relationship!= nil

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-data

There's a **transient optional relationship (no inverse)** in my Entity. Fetching with the predicate

```
NSPredicate(format: "name LIKE\(option) (%@) AND tc!=nil", name)
```

gives no result, which isn't as expected. The `tc` is computed from another relationship.

If the part after AND and "AND" are removed, the fetch works well.

The transient property is implemented like this:

```
public var tc : TC?  {
    self.willAccessValue(forKey: "tc")
    self.didAccessValue(forKey: "tc")

    return friend?.parent
}
```

I've noticed **the fetch didn't hit the debug breakpoint** inside this `tc` accessor.
There's no error message printed in the console.

What did I miss?

---

Edit:

After reading Ron's comment I googled more and found:

- [Core Data Transient-Like Attributes that are Compatible with NSPredicate](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Core_Data_Transient_Like_Attributes_that_are_Com-iV7)  This is not an option for me since the actual transient relationship is more expensive to calculate.
- [How to use NSPredicate with chained virtual
  property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592473/how-to-use-nspredicate-with-chained-virtual-property)
- [NSPredicate not working with calculated
  field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267229/nspredicate-not-working-with-calculated-field)
- [Core Data : Searching using transient attributes as criteria](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/164969-core-data-searching-using-transient-attributes-as-criteria.html)

The answers with transient properties were the same.

I didn't found those at first. Perhaps I was too focus on `nil` or `relationship`. We can fetch by relationship with `nil` as long as it's not transient:

[iPhone SDK Core Data: Fetch all entities with a nil relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745994/iphone-sdk-core-data-fetch-all-entities-with-a-nil-relationship)

Apple's doc on transient properties is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html).

Comment: You can't use transient property for fetch requests. Use the real property that is stored in the db.

Comment: Just thinking about debugging the core data SQL stuff. You saved my life. But what's the difference between transient relationship and a plain computed property? Thank you! (Just forgot to say.)

Comment: A computed property usually is computed on the fly, when you access it. Therefore it does not have a setter and it is not stored in the object itself. A transient property can be a full, ivar-backed property. It is stored in the object. But if the object persists, it is not saved. It is like a "temporary property".

Comment: Computed properties can also be cached by hand, but they don't work with an undo manager.